# Applescript: make new folder using a simple repeat/end repeat to check if name exists

Tags: loops, applescript, repeat

I am trying to create a script which creates a new client folder. No real drama there but I'm running aground when I try to add a bit of functionality which checks to see whether the folder exists. If false, it will go ahead and create the folder and if true, it will repeat the initial question (and check) until the user enters a client name that does not exist. The problem I've got is I can get it to check and/or create a folder after it has checked but I can't get the loop to stop once it has created a folder.

Here's what I've managed thus far

```
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat
    set newClientName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter New Client Name" default answer "")
    set thePath to "MATRIX:Designs:Digital:Clients:"
    set theFolder to thePath & newClientName

    if (theFolder exists) = true then
        display dialog "There is already a Client with that name"

    else
        make new folder at thePath with properties {name:newClientName}

    end if

    end repeat
end tell
```

Any direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `exit repeat` the loop on success.

You should check for a `folder` rather than a literal string path

```
set thePath to "MATRIX:Designs:Digital:Clients:"
tell application "Finder"
    activate
    repeat
        set newClientName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter New Client Name" default answer "")
        if exists folder newClientName of folder thePath then
            display dialog "There is already a Client with that name"
        else
            make new folder at folder thePath with properties {name:newClientName}
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Vadian for both the solution and the tip. I feel repeat loops is my next chapter to master!